# Swift - tableview.reloadData() crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am fetching some data from a plist into a UITableview. 
I am trying to delete the data selected however, when I try to reload the data to show just the remaining cells the app crashes. 
I think the problem is when I use `tableview.reloadData()` but I am not sure how to fix this problem. If I don't use reloadData the cell will be deleted when I reopen the view controller.

Any Advice?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

            let row = indexPath.row

            let plistPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
            let DocumentsDirectory = plistPath[0] as! String
            let path = DocumentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("notes.plist")
            let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

            if (!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {

                if let bundlePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("notes", ofType: "plist") {

                    let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlePath)
                    println("Bundle notes.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
                    fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundlePath, toPath: path, error: nil)
                    println("copy")

                } else {
                    println("notes.plist not found")
                }


            } else {
                println("note.plist already exists")

                //fileManager.removeItemAtPath(path, error: nil)
            }

            let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
            //resultDictionary?.removeAllObjects()
            resultDictionary?.removeObjectForKey(allKeys[row])
            resultDictionary!.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)

            println("Loaded notes.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")


            tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Provide details about the crash.

Comment: The app crashes saying: 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) '

Comment: On which line did this error happen?

Comment: please see picturer attached

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the first line of that method. Then once the program pauses on that breakpoint, step through until you hit the crash. This will tell you which line is causing the crash.

Comment: it crashes at tableView.reloadData(), last line

Answer (score 3):

About calling reloadData(), the documentation says: "It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block implemented with calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates." so its better to just reload the section where you made the changes and call begin and end if animation is involved

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(path, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

and also its preferable to use your own instance of nsfilemanager since the default one works only in the main thread. and also you're unsafely unwrapping resultDictionary when writing to file, that could cause crash 
ps,

```
let path = DocumentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("notes.plist")
```

is replaced by stringByAppendingString n swift 2, just fyi

Comment: thank you... I have been trying but I get error:    Cannot invoke 'reloadRowsAtIndexPaths' with an argument list of type '((String), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation)'